# Save PC time in Sql server time datatype and read in back in QT

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, qt, time

I am working on a QT project in C++. I want to save PC time in SQL db along with one int field. When I execute the command to save time in DB it does not throw any error, but when I retrieve the time from db it gives following result for time field **\025**

query sp_columns test return's following:

```
sNo  int
timeVar time
```

Query to save time in table:

```
QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
QString timeString = time.toString("hh:mm:ss");
timeString = QString("%1").arg(timeString);

query = QString("Insert into test values(1,'%1')").arg(timeString);
qry->prepare(query);
qry->exec();
```

Query to fetch time from table

```
query = QString("select * from test");
qry->prepare(query);
qry->exec();

    QString sNo;
    QString timeString;
    int noOfRecords;
    noOfRecords = qry->numRowsAffected();
    do{
    sNo = qry->value(0).toString();
    time = qry->value(1).toTime(); //it returns invalid here
    timeString = qry->value(1).toString(); // Here it retrurns "\025"
    }while(qry->next());
```

Comment: Why don't you do `while (qry-next()) { ... }` instead? I think you should call `next()` on your query before reading its values.

Comment: @vahancho Also checked in QT SQL page the way described by you is the right way to read values.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the following:

- Qt SQL plugins support many of the native Qt types like QTime so you shouldn't convert it to string.
- No need to create a QSqlQuery pointer.
- Do not concatenate to create a query by concatenating strings since it is susceptible to SQL Injection.

Considering the above, the solution is:

(not tested)

```cpp
QTime time = QTime::currentTime();

QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("INSERT INTO test values(?, ?)");
qry.addBindValue(1);
qry.addBindValue(time);
qry.exec();
```

```cpp
QSqlQuery qry("select * from test");
while (qry.next()) {
    QString sNo = qry->value(0).toString();
    QTime time = qry->value(1).toTime();
    qDebug() << sNo << time;
}
```

Comment: I am still getting time field as  invalid after this
QTime time = qry->value(1).toTime();

Comment: @Aerensingh what is the output of `qDebug() << qry->value(1);`?

Comment: The output is
 QVariant(QByteArray, "\f\x00""4\x00.\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")

Comment: @Aerensingh Have you verified if the information is saved in the database?

Comment: Yes the information is stored in the database. In DB it is showing both sNo and time as below

1                      12:52:46.00000

Comment: @Aerensingh okay, what is the output of  `qDebug() << qry.value(1).toString();`?

Comment: qDebug() << qry.value(1).toString() returns  "\r"

Comment: @Aerensingh Have you deleted all the rows from the table before using my code?

Comment: @eyIIanesc Yes I have truncated the table before using your code